# Html Javascript website remove horizontal scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

This is a subject covered extensively on this website and other forums. Other users have claimed the solutions posted fixed their horizontal scroll problem, but none have worked for me. Some answers have suggested using jQuery to offset the scroll problem, but before I go down that road I wanted to get a second opinion.

Here is a link to my codepen:

http://codepen.io/dsemel/pen/WrYBye

And this didn't work..

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no"/>
```

It looks okay on my laptop but slides around on my iPhone.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your website had a horizontal scroll bar is because the `<p>` elements had a fixed width of `400px` I've changed that to `100%` and everything is working fine.

Here's a snippet of the fixed `<p>` styling at `line 36`:

```
p {
  padding-bottom:100px;
  height:100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Also, the meta viewport tag should be <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; user-scalable=no" />

Comment: Thank you Emad. I really appreciate it, it's funny how much trouble little details like that can cause and how it important it is to be aware of them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**hello,**

Use `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no" />` in order to set width to device width.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer just advice*

I had this problem, realised that there was default padding on couple of my divs. Just check your padding % on your divs may be effecting overflow issues. Also spelling mistake on your css... overflow-y: has hideen not hidden. sorry I couldn't be more helpful, good luck....

```
html{
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:hideen;} ***change for hidden***
```